# Take screenshot of webpage along with the browser window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am generating custom reports by implementing `IReporter`. I am able to take screenshot of the entire page using the following code

```
((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

This captures only the HTML webpage, but I want to capture the browser window as well. Use case for this is say, suppose I check for the title of the page and assert fails. So, when I see the screenshot, I can see what the title of the page was at that time.

Comment: for getting the title you can validate using `driver.getTitle();` What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I can validate the title, but to verify that, I need to see the title in the captured screenshot. But the title is visible only on the browser tab/window, which is not part of the webpage screenshot

Comment: @Rakesh, how are you planning to automatically achieve that?

Comment: There are two ways, 1- use webdriver to capture entire page (without the browser window), 2 - use Robot class to capture the desktop screen, but the 2nd method doesn't give me the entire page. I am thinking of a combined solution to capture the browser window as well.

Comment: @Rakesh If you just want to check window title if test fails, store the page title obtained by `driver.getTitle()` and check it later. Taking screenshot just to see title isnt a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can get screenshot of the full desktop using Java Robot library. See this [article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-take-screen-shots-in-java-taking-screenshots-java/) for implementation details.